Why did Protestants think Revelation's "Mother of harlots" represented the Roman Church but didn't recognize themselves as the "harlot daughters"?
Revelation 7 describes a woman (symbolizing a church):

3 … and I saw a woman sit upon a scarlet coloured beast, full of names of blasphemy, having seven heads and ten horns.
4 And the woman was arrayed in purple and scarlet colour, and decked with gold and precious stones and pearls, having a golden cup in her hand full of abominations and filthiness of her fornication:
5 And upon her forehead was a name written, MYSTERY, BABYLON THE GREAT, THE MOTHER OF HARLOTS AND ABOMINATIONS OF THE EARTH.
6 And I saw the woman drunken with the blood of the saints, and with the blood of the martyrs of Jesus: and when I saw her, I wondered with great admiration.

Whore of Babylon - Wikipedia says of this scripture:

Reformation view
Historicist interpreters commonly used the phrase "Whore of Babylon" to refer to the Catholic Church.
Reformation writers Martin Luther (1483–1546, author of On the Babylonian Captivity of the Church), John Calvin (1509–1564), and John Knox (1510–1572, author of The First Blast of the Trumpet Against the Monstruous Regiment of Women) taught this association.
Most early Protestant Reformers believed, and the modern Seventh-day Adventist Church teaches, that in Bible prophecy a woman represents a church.
The connection noted on the seven hills of Rome is argued to locate the church.

This "whore" church is described as being a "mother of harlots".

Catholics refer to their Church as the "Holy Mother Church".
Protestants saw this "whore" as representing the Roman Church, but failed to recognize the corresponding relationship between the church's "harlot daughters" and their own churches.
Did they have a rational explanation of why these daughters don't represent their own Protestant denominations?

Note that my intent is not to insult almost everyone except for SDAs; I'm truly curious about this connection that apparently isn't as obvious as it seems to be.

This is historically incorrect. Protestant congregations did not come from Catholic churches in the way that daughters come from mothers. Individuals gathered from various quarters and, being born again, were gathered into One Body under the Headship of Jesus Christ. That some saw a certain body as representing 'Babylon' in a particular generation is understandable, but it is not exegetically correct interpretation for Babylon is an age-long concept not a localised incident.

@NigelJ, my question isn't about whether the identification with Rome is correct. That the early Protestant reformers did make this identification is a given fact.

No, of course. Your question is hypothetical. If it be true that there is a mother-daughter relationship then why did some not recognise it. But that 'if it be true' is hypothetical.

@NigelJ where are you getting that question, I don't see it in the OP. A scripture is quoted, a background is laid, and then a question is formed. I think there is enough of a comparison, as Protestant did branch from Catholicism (https://www.britannica.com/topic/Roman-Catholicism/The-age-of-Reformation-and-Counter-Reformation and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_denomination#Taxonomy)


OP Was this deliberate blindness, or did they have a rational explanation of why these daughters don't represent their own Protestant denominations?

To have a daughter from a mother, it implies a like DNA, a similar result, mannerisms, beliefs, and practices (to move a bit out of the physical into the spiritual).
With that in mind, the Reformers did not see themselves as coming from the Roman Catholic Church, but were mindful of restoration of the things that once were.
A clear example is the RC view of communion as both a sacrifice and sacrament.  The Reformers rejected the sacrifice ideas as extra-biblical, historical, and as mere tradition, but retained the sacrament part.
Another example would be in the number of books of the Bible, keeping the original 66 and rejecting the 73.
Reformers rejected Tradition as defined by man.
The Reformers rejected purgatory and indulgences and Seat of Peter as boss (Papal authority) and sacerdotal priesthood and many other, in their view, false beliefs and practices that had evolved away from Christianity.
In other words, one cannot be a daughter of a Mother who have diametrically opposed ideas, beliefs, practices, and salvific answers.
